# Ruby Hangman - how to find the index of a matching letter in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Ruby noob. Trying to build a hangman game and use the following code to find the index so I can replace the dashes with the guessed letter when a players guesses correctly. The words are from a json database. @letter and @word are added here as an example, and instance variables are used because I'm def methods in the full code.

Any ideas why this is not working? Can 'find_index' return multiple values for every place it finds the letter? If 'find_index' doesn't return multiple values is there an array method which does?

```
@word = "elephant"
@letter = "e"
@word = @word.split
@index = @word.find_index(@letter)
puts "the index is #{@index}"
```

Comment: Use String#chars, not String#split.

Comment: Ask yourself how _you_ know where the occurrences of e in elephant are. Now express that same procedure in Ruby.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [Return index of all occurrences of a character in a string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1819540/477037)

Comment: @Stefan yes that does help!

Comment: Based on @matt 's comment though I worked on some other approaches and settled on using scan without converting the string with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520208/get-index-of-string-scan-results-in-ruby to find the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want indices for all characters in `@word` for `@letter`.  If this is the case, then the following should work:

```rb
@word.chars.each_with_index.select { |c, i| c == @letter }.map(&:last)
```

Breaking this down...

- `#chars` returns an array of the characters in the word
- `#each_with_index` returns an `Enumerator` that yields the character and the iteration index
- `#select` is used to filter the array to character:index pairs, where the character matches `@letter`
- `#map` iterates over the filtered array of character:index pairs and returns the last element for each pair (i.e. the index).